# Passing Range Object to Public Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass a Range Object from the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to another function and then set it to a public variable. 
This is a snippet of the code I have so far.

### Code in "Sheet1"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C8:C65000"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        eventPicker.showEventPickerForm Target
    End If
End Sub
```

### Code in "eventPicker" Form

```
Public eventTarget as Range

Sub showEventPickerForm(ByVal targetCell as Range)
    Set eventTarget = targetCell
    eventPicker.show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MsgBox(eventTarget.Address)
End Sub
```

Running this code gives me the following error

> Object variable or With block variable not set

with the debugger highlighting `eventPicker.showEventPickerForm Target`.
Commenting out the `MsgBox(eventTarget.Address)` line allows the code to run as expected.

I have tried moving the public variable declaration to outside the form in its own module, changing the `MsgBox` call to the following

```
With eventTarget
    MsgBox(.Address)
End With
```

I've also tried passing the parameter `ByRef` as opposed to `ByVal` all returning the same error as above.

My thinking is that the object is being reset to null at some point as I can refer to eventTarget after the `Set` call in the `showEventPickerForm` function, but my research suggests that publicly declared variables will hold their value for as long as the workbook remains open. I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Break on Change shows the object being set to 'Nothing' on call of `End Sub` in `showEventPickerForm` and assigning the value in the selection change event gives the same error message.

Comment: Some discussion here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/127789-pass-target-variable-from-worksheet-change-event-to-userform-textbox

Comment: In relation to link ^^  I think you can store values in named ranges that don't actually have a sheet range address. Trick I think I have seen elsewhere.

Comment: And see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288997/excel-vba-pass-variable-from-sub-to-userform

Comment: Thank you, moving the showEventPickerForm sub to a module along with the public variable fixed the issue.
I looked at that question earlier but did not appreciate the distinction of moving just the public variable and both the sub and public variable