# Variable not available on UseerForm_Initialize event

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass row number to UserForm, so it could display data in user friendly way for end user, but having trouble catching this variable on Initialize moment.

Code in the Worksheet module, it should open UserForm and pass row number as variable:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim DataRange As ListObject
Dim xRow As Long

xRow = Target.Row
Set DataRange = Sheets("Forecast").ListObjects("ForecastTable")

If Application.Intersect(Target, DataRange.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox xRow
    With FullInfo
        .MyProp = xRow
        .Show
    End With
    
End If
End Sub
```

This is the code in UserForm:

```
Property Let MyProp(xRow As Long)
    publicRow = xRow
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim publicRow As Long

MsgBox publicRow
 
End Sub
```

From `MsgBox` I used for testing I determined that code in the sheet module returns correct row number, but then UserForm is initialized it shows 0 as no data is received. Interestingly enough, I put a button in the user form for testing with following code:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

MsgBox publicRow

End Sub
```

After pressing it - it shows correct row number, so it means it passed but only after Initialize event. How should I pass variable to UserForm so it would be available at `Initialize` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you. :)
...so this is your code corrected ...

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

     Dim DataRange As ListObject
     Dim xRow As Integer
     Dim FullInfo As Object

     xRow = Target.Row
     Set DataRange = Sheets("Forecast").ListObjects("Tabela1")

     If Application.Intersect(Target, DataRange.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Or 
     Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
     Else
     Set FullInfo = New UserForm1
        
    With FullInfo
     .Label1.Caption = xRow
     .Show
    End With
    
    End If
    End Sub
```

... if you want to go further, I have another way to pass a public variable to userForm

1. You code in sheet

   ```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim DataRange2 As ListObject
    Dim xRow As Integer

    xRow = Target.Row
    Set DataRange2 = Sheets("Arkusz1").ListObjects("Tabela2")

    If Application.Intersect(Target, DataRange2.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Or 
    Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
    Else

    Call UserFormStart(xRow)

    End If
    End Sub
   ```
2. Put code to new module (in the worksheet do not work)

   ```
    'Public rowSelection As Integer  'declare public variable
    Public Sub UserFormStart(ByVal rowRef As Integer)

      rowSelection = rowRef  
      UserForm1.Show

    End Sub
   ```
3. In your userForm

   ```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox rowSelection & " it's work"
    End Sub

    Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MsgBox rowSelection
    End Sub
   ```

It works for me :)

You can check one topic

[Excel - VBA : pass variable from Sub to Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288997/excel-vba-pass-variable-from-sub-to-userform)